# Monaco-Editor: Activate only certain lines for editing

Tags: colors, line, readonly, monaco-editor

I would like to activate only certain lines for editing. To do this, the other lines should be lightly grayed out. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? So far I have only found a workaround (see the code below) that does not have the other lines grayed out and can also be selected with [Ctrl] + [A]. The danger is then that the removal works.

```
this.editor.layoutOverlayWidget()
this.editor.onDidChangeCursorPosition((e) => {
  if (e.position.lineNumber < 3 || e.position.lineNumber > 3) {
    this.editor.setPosition({
      lineNumber: 3,
      column: 1
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You can check change and trigger some undo if needed

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?